# Wait for codebuild and get build result using aws cli or boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to wait for a codebuild build and get the result of the build using the aws cli or boto3. There does not seem to be any command for this. All I can do is list builds, but only the build-ids. There is not information about the build (if it is still running and what the build result is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the build ID to batch-get-builds:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/batch-get-builds.html

Comment: Any idea how to wait until after the build finishes before running batch-get-builds?  Codebuild doesn't seem to have any waiters in Boto3.

Comment: @David For now, you'd need to do your own loop with a sleep in between calls to batch-get-builds.  I recommend reaching out to the CodeBuild team on their AWS forum, as they would need to submit the SDK change to add a waiter. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I ended up doing - thanks for following up though

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can create an event rule to trigger on Codebuild's success. With that, you may listen the event to continue your task.