# How to wait for a CodeBuild project to finish building before finishing a Boto3 unit test?

Tags: boto3, python-unittest, aws-codebuild

When writing a Python Boto3 unittest for CodeBuild, is it possible to start_build() and then wait() for the build to complete before evaluating whether or not my test passed?  Normally, I'd just use a waiter, but CodeBuild doesn't have any waiters as far as I can tell (I did client.waiter_names and got an empty arrray, and the Boto3 documentation doesn't list any waiters for the CodeBuild client).

I found [this (duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407953/wait-for-codebuild-and-get-build-result-using-aws-cli-or-boto3), but the answer doesn't address how to actually solve the problem of waiting - it just says how to check the status of a build.  That would be useful if I could somehow wait() until the status changed to a certain value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up never finding a good solution to this, so I just made a loop that'll poll the status until it's finished.

```
      client = boto3.client(service_name='codebuild', region_name='us-east-1')
      new_build = client.start_build(projectName='fooProject')
      buildId = new_build['build']['id']

      buildSucceeded = False

      counter = 0
      while counter < 10:   #capped this, so it just fails if it takes too long
        time.sleep(5)
        counter = counter + 1
        theBuild = client.batch_get_builds(ids=[buildId])
        buildStatus = theBuild['builds'][0]['buildStatus']

        if buildStatus == 'SUCCEEDED':
          buildSucceeded = True
          break
        elif buildStatus == 'FAILED' or buildStatus == 'FAULT' or buildStatus == 'STOPPED' or buildStatus == 'TIMED_OUT':
          break

      self.assertTrue(buildSucceeded)
```

Comment: Thanks, this idea helped me. To improve this, I am checking for the build's endTime as the condition of the while loop, sleeping still but not stopping until the build finished.

Comment: boto3 seems to support `get_waiter()` but it's not clear if CodeBuild has any available waiters ? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codebuild.html#CodeBuild.Client.get_waiter